# Wait for Angular 2 to load/resolve FormBuilder/ControlGroups before rendering view/template

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Is there a way to tell Angular2 to wait until a `FormBuilder` and its elements *(with their associated default values)* have loaded before rendering the template?

Currently I have the following in my form

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submitFees()" [ngFormModel]="FeeForm">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input type="number" id="Fees" class="form-control"
        placeholder="Fee" required
       [ngFormControl]="FeeForm.controls['ContentFee']"
        [(ngModel)]="Fee">
      </div>
     Fee: {{postFee*1.2| number:'1.2-2'}}
  </div>
</form>
```

and in my constructor:

```
constructor(){
    let fb = new FormBuilder();
    this.FeeForm = fb.group({
        ContentFee: ['0', Validators.required]
    });
}
```

However on the page load, before I edit the fee the value shows up as NaN, ideally I would like to have it show its default (0.00) on page load.

How would I accomplish this?

**EDIT**

I notice that if user [(ngModel)] that the defaults of FormBuilder are no longer available (when I try submit a blank form and log the FeeForm.value i get undefined). Is there away around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using the deprecated forms in RC1, I know this works with the new forms in RC2+

If you have a field Fee in your component you can set the initial value for the form in the constructor.

```
constructor(){
    this.Fee = 0 // This will show up as the default value 
    let fb = new FormBuilder();
    this.FeeForm = fb.group({
        ContentFee: ['0', Validators.required] // Value not used
    });
}
```