# Angular2 FormBuilder default values no longer available when using ngModel

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have noticed that when using `[(ngModel)]` I am no longer able to take advantage of the *default* values provided by `FormBuilder`.

Currently I have the following in my form

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submitFees()" [ngFormModel]="FeeForm">
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <input type="number" id="Fees" class="form-control"
        placeholder="Fee" required
       [ngFormControl]="FeeForm.controls['ContentFee']"
        [(ngModel)]="Fee">
      </div>
     Fee: {{postFee*1.2| number:'1.2-2'}}
  </div>
</form>
```

and in my constructor:

```
constructor(){
    let fb = new FormBuilder();
    this.FeeForm = fb.group({
        ContentFee: ['0', Validators.required]
    });
}
```

This gives me a `NaN` for `{{postFee}}`
and when I submit the form and `console.log(FeeForm.value)` I get `ContentFee:undefined`. however if I remove `[(ngModel)]` all works as expected.

How would I be able to still make use of *default* values with `[(ngModel)]`?

Answer (score 1):

[From my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37987648/wait-for-angular-2-to-load-resolve-formbuilder-controlgroups-before-rendering-vi) it seems that what is needed is to include the initialisation for the in the constructor like this:

```
constructor(){
    this.Fee = 0 // This will show up as the default value 
    let fb = new FormBuilder();
    this.FeeForm = fb.group({
        ContentFee: ['0', Validators.required] // Value not used
    });
}
```